# Оставить особые точки те, которые попадают в прямоугольник с координатами (x1,y1) и (x2,y2)

Tags: python

Получил особые точки алгоритмом orb: `kp1`, `kp2` и высчитал индексы `matches` (массив `DMatch`)(`matches` отсортировал по дистанции) Мне нужно оставить особые точки те, которые попадают во внутрь прямоугольника с координатами вершин (`x1`, `y1`) и (`x2`, `y2`). Проверку эту сделал, осталось только удалить точку, как это сделать, подскажите?

```
img1, kp1, des1 = image_detect_and_compute(detector, img1)
img2, kp2, des2 = image_detect_and_compute(detector, img2)
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
if des1 is not None and des2 is not None:
    matches = bf.match(des1, des2)
    matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)
```

Comment: Стороны прямоугольника параллельны осям координат?

Comment: это неважно, так как точки kp1[i].pt и (x1,y1) и (x2,y2) - в одних плоскостях!!!
вопрос не об этом!

Comment: @Евгений я уже определил что точка находится в прямоугольнике или нет! вопрос как мне удалить эту точку с kp1, kp2 и также с индекса DMatch (вот это проблема у меня! ) причем тут оси координат???

Comment: В таком случае переформулируйте, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, чтобы сделать его менее общим. Уберите фрагмент о поиске вхождения точек и оставьте только то, что вам нужно удалить точку из kp1, kp2 и DMatch. Текущую формулировку вопроса считаю слишком общей.

Comment: @Евгений изменил